# Change order of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm stuck on how to change the order of integration for this question,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\cos x}^1\, f(x,y)\,\,\,dydx $$

We know that if we take vertical strips of the original integral the boundaries are

$\cos x \le y \le 1$

$0 \le x \le 2\pi$

Which is easy to integrate for, the answer being $2\pi$. However I am unsure how to obtain the boundaries for the horizontal strips through changing the order of integration.

I suspect that we have $-1 \le y \le 1$ for the y terminals but uncertain for the x terminals. Am I right in setting the y terminals to this?

The final answer by either taking horizontal or vertical strips should be $2\pi$

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: You'll need to play around with $\arccos$ (sometimes written $\cos^{-1}$). Remember that, by definition, $0\le\arccos(y)\le\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you sketch the curves $y = \cos x$ and $y=1$.

Now, draw a horizontal line across this region.  How would you express the endpoints in terms of y?

Comment: I'm assuming the terminals are $arccosy \le x \le 2\pi$, which would involve some integration by parts?

Comment: You have the left endpoint correct but not the right endpoint.  Is $(2\pi,0)$ in your region?  You may need to integrate by parts, it would depend on what f(x,y) looks like.